# app_offline.htm not working in iis6

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

I created app_offline.htm (3kb) in the root of my virtual folder.
In IIS7 it works like a charm.

In II6 it is being ignored.
So I added the file to the  document sections of the app properties and moved it all the way to the top.
That works when I go straight to the site, however, when I add a page after the url, for instance www.test.com/login.asp it ignores app_offline.htm and shows the login page.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Is your `app_offline.htm` added into the root of the application (in other words is the root of your site defined as an ASP Application)?

Comment: Yes, it is added into the root and yes it's defined as ASP application.